# returning variables in a function swift

Tags: swift

I will make a Login and the post request is in the function.
In the if statement `if dict!["Authorized"] as AnyObject? === true as AnyObject` i would like to return if the Authorization is true.
But the error when want to return is `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`
I tried to declare the func as an Bool or any other statement like this `-> Bool`.
But that doesen't work.
Here is my code.

```
func Login(Benutzer: String, Password: String) {


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://mydomain/ajax/login.php")!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "Benutzername=\(String(describing: Benutzer))&Password=\(String(describing: Password))"
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                  // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if error as AnyObject? === "The Internet is Down" as AnyObject {
            }
        else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You have to turn on your Internet or Server is Down ", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }

                }
                    return
                }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                                }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

        func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
            if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
                do {
                    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                            }
                               return nil
                           }

        let dict = convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if dict!["Authorized"] as AnyObject? === true as AnyObject {

                    return true
                    // error is here

                }

            else {


                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: dict!["Message"] as? String, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                        }
                    }
                }
                task.resume()

    }



    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let Benutzer = benutzernameTextField.text;
        let Password = passwordTextField.text;

        if benutzernameTextField.text == Benutzer && passwordTextField.text == Password {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `throw` for errors? And, also, you can't `return` the result from an async call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that at one point in the function you have just `return` and at another point in the function you have `return true`. Swift is strongly typed and a function always has to return the same type - you can't return a bool in one case and nothing in another. What you probably want to do is change the first `return` to `return false` and then add `-> Bool` to the function's signature. Another option would be to return an optional bool (-> Bool?) and return nil in the first case. Also, as a side note, you probably want to lowercase the "L" in "Login" - that's just convention.

```
func Login(Benutzer: String, Password: String) -> Bool {


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://mydomain/ajax/login.php")!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "Benutzername=\(String(describing: Benutzer))&Password=\(String(describing: Password))"
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                  // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if error as AnyObject? === "The Internet is Down" as AnyObject {
            }
        else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You have to turn on your Internet or Server is Down ", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }

                }
                    return false
                }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                                }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

        func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
            if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
                do {
                    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                            }
                               return nil
                           }

        let dict = convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if dict!["Authorized"] as AnyObject? === true as AnyObject {

                    return true

                }

            else {


                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: dict!["Message"] as? String, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                        }
                    }
                }
                task.resume()

    }



    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let Benutzer = benutzernameTextField.text;
        let Password = passwordTextField.text;

        if benutzernameTextField.text == Benutzer && passwordTextField.text == Password {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also `throw` an error. Or return a `Result`